# Template class compiles with C++17 but not with C++20 if unused function can't be compiled

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

The following compiles without error in VS2019 (version 16.11.15) with C++ 17 selected as the language. But it fails with C++ 20 with error "error C2027: use of undefined type 'Anon'"

```
template <typename T> class a_template
{
public:
    void do_something(class Anon& anon) const;
};

template <typename T> void a_template<T>::do_something(class Anon& anon) const
{
    anon.do_something();
}
```

The `Anon` class is of course undefined but the ::do_something function is unused so does not need to be instantiated. This is OK in C++17 but apparently not in C++20.

Is this a change in language rules? If so, can it be fixed without actually defining `Anon`?

Comment: On MSVC, the flag `/std:c++20` also enables flag [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170). I guess that if you specify  `/permissive-` on C++17, the code might be rejected as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a change in language rules?

No, this is due to the fact that **a C++ compiler is permitted (but not required!) to diagnose errors at the time the template is parsed
when all of the instantiations of the template would produce that error**.

This means that for your given example, at the time of parsing the definition compilers may or may not issue an error. That is, the compiler can produce an error when parsing the template or may wait until the first template instantiation. Refer to [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1b5WrasP4) where msvc doesn't issue an error but gcc and clang does.

Perhaps a simpler example would make it more clear :

```
void func()
{

}

template<typename T> void bar() 
{
     func(3); //compilers are allowed(but not required) to issue error at the time of pasrsing this
}
```

In the above example, `func` is a **nondependent name** and at the point where we have called `func` using `func(3)`, the only visible `func` is the one that accepts `0` arguments and not one. And as i said earlier, some compiler may issue an error(at the time of parsing) even though we've not instantiated `bar`  but some compilers may not. This is because they are allowed to but not required to do so. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1b5WrasP4) where msvc doesn't issue an error here but gcc and clang does.

---

The same logic applies to your example as well. Meaning as `Anon` is an incomplete type and you have `anon.do_something()`, some compiler might choose to produce an error even though you have not instantiated `a_template` and some other compiler might not.

Comment: You should probably roll in @prapin's comment about the `/permissive-` flag.

Comment: With /permissive-, the same error is generated with C++ 17. With C++ 20 /permissive setting makes no difference