# why was invalid substitution of class template deriving template arguments in alias declaration not resulting in error

Tags: c++, templates

I have tested these several templates to show the validity of the template instantiation:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using LRef = T&;

template <typename T>
using Ptr = T*;

template <typename>
  requires false
class A {};

// ...

using T0 = LRef<int>;  // expected ok
// using T1 = LRef<void>; // expected error, forming void& which is invalid
using T2 = Ptr<void>;  // expected ok
// using T3 = Ptr<int&>;  // expected error, forming int& * which is invalid
// using T4 = A<int>;     // expected error, unsatisfied constraint resulting in invalid instantiation
```

However,

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Box { T value; };

template <typename T, typename U = T>
struct Derive : T, U {};

// ...
using T5 = Derive<int, float>; // unexpected no-error, but should be invalid
// template struct Derive<int, float>; // expected error

using T6 = Derive<Box<int>, Box<float>>; // expected ok
template struct Derive<Box<int>, Box<float>>; // expected ok

using T7 = Derive<Box<int>>; // unexpected no-error, but should be invalid
// template struct Derive<Box<int>>; // expected error

void foo() {
    // T5 {}; // error
    // T7 {}; // error
}
```

type alias declarations of `T5` and `T7` have no error, which are unexpected. I suppose that they should be invalid since the explicit instantiation with the same template arguments and the usage of type alias has errors.

Is this the correct behavior in standard C++ or just not implemented properly? These 3 major compilers (GCC, Clang, and MSVC) show no compilation error with this program. https://godbolt.org/z/hcbszo49a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this valid in standard C++ or just not implemented properly?

The [second snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/eTW3jGv5v) without the use of `T5{};` and `T7{};` is well-formed.

This is because `typedef`s, `using` and do not require a completely defined type. And from [implicit instantiation's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation):

> When code refers to a template in context that requires a completely defined type, or when the completeness of the type affects the code, and this particular type has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs. **For example, when an object of this type is constructed, but not when a pointer to this type is constructed**.

(emphasis mine)

And as  **type alias** doesn't require a completely defined type, according to the above quoted statement there will be no implicit instantiation for a `typedef` or `using`.

For example:

```
template<typename T> struct C{ T& k;};
using V = C<void>; //no implicit instantiation
int main()
{
    C<int>* k;//no implicit instantiation
    C<void>* l; //no implicit instantiation
   
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WMbWqWozd)

---

> They should be invalid since the explicit instantiation with the same template arguments and the usage of type alias has errors.

Note in first snippet where you use an **alias template** instead of a class template, all compilers seem to produce the error([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c1ax79Kve)) you mentioned but this is because they are allowed(but not required) to do so as also explained in [Template class compiles with C++17 but not with C++20 if unused function can't be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375794/template-class-compiles-with-c17-but-not-with-c20-if-unused-function-cant-b/72376365#72376365).