# Problems with friends of class template

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I am trying to create some friends functions for my class template. I know you have to declare them outside the class first but I am having some weird results.

...

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix<T>& mtrx);
template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const Matrix<T>& mtrx);
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator*(const T& t, const Matrix<T>& mtrx);

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:

    friend std::ostream&    operator<< <>(std::ostream&, const Matrix&);
    friend std::istream&    operator>> <>(std::istream&, const Matrix&);

    Matrix                  operator*(const T&) const;
    friend Matrix<T>        operator* <>(const T& t, const Matrix& mtrx);
};
```

...

The two stream operators work fine for me, but the multiplication operator has issues. For some reason the compiler (Visual Studio) seems to think I am trying to declare a data member and keeps throwing a bunch of errors. Like

```
C2460 uses Matrix which is being defined; 
C2433 friend not permitted on data declarations; 
c2473 looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.
```

As far as I can tell, the implementation is the same as for the stream operators which work. Also, if I rename operator* to something else, like foo, it works fine.

Now, I don't actually need to make this function a friend, my definition just reverses order of arguments and calls the member function version. But I still want to know what is going on and what is wrong.

Comment: The program compiles in gcc and clang: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bd8h4j4sn)

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug then, I was inclined to believe something like that, but wanted to check. Thanks.

Comment: Changing order of declaration of `operator*` seems to bypass the msvc bug [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4bvahnxEv)

Comment: @Jarod42 I've added some explanation why this might happen here. Note also that with C++17 the program is rejected with all compilers as stated in my answer. Moreover, if we instantiate `Matrix` for some template argument then the same program is rejected by gcc as well which i think is correct.

Comment: @HanLi Since you've not instantiated `Matrix`, it is not a msvc bug. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386581/12002570) below.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here.

##### First

A C++ compiler is permitted (but not required!) to diagnose errors at the time the template is parsed when all of the instantiations of the template would produce that error.

This means that since you've not instantiated class template `Matrix`, compilers are free to diagnose the error. For example, the given program is rejected by msvc but accepted(compiled) by gcc and clang in C++20. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/16v9W3fMb).

So this is not msvc bug. For more detailed explanation of this, refer to [Template class compiles with C++17 but not with C++20 if unused function can't be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375794/template-class-compiles-with-c17-but-not-with-c20-if-unused-function-cant-b/72376365#72376365).

Note also that if you do instantiate `Matrix` for some template argument say by writing `Matrix<int>`, then the program is also rejected by gcc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nPW89sM57). See reason why this is rejected.

---

##### Important

The important thing to note here is that the exact same program is rejected by all compilers with C++17 irrespective of whether you instantiate `Matrix` for a given template argument or not. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jGjehEbMj)

---

##### Second

Now, lets see the reason for the program being rejected with all compilers in C++17.

In your given program when you try to befriend a specialization of the function template `operator*`, the compiler starts lookup(looking up) for an `operator*` and it finds the non-template overloaded version and so **stops looking further**. Now, since it found a nontemplate version which cannot be specialized, it gives the [error](https://godbolt.org/z/b6rvs3r8r) in all compilers.

Lets, look at a contrived example:

```
template<typename T> void f(T){

}
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:


    int                  f(const T&) const; //#1
    friend void          f<>(const Matrix& mtrx); //lookup find #1 and stops looking and so gives error
    
};;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> m;
}
```

To solve the above error, it we've to reorder the declarations so that the lookup for `operator*` isn't found when befriending the specialization.

This means we have to change the above program to:

```
template<typename T> void f(T){ //#2

}
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:


    
    friend void          f<>(const Matrix& mtrx); //lookup find #2  
    int                  f(const T&) const; //OK now
};;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> m;
}
```

---

##### Summary

To solve the error you're getting you've to reorder the declarations for `operator*` like shown below:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:

    friend std::ostream&    operator<< <>(std::ostream&, const Matrix&);
    friend std::istream&    operator>> <>(std::istream&, const Matrix&);

    //reordered 
    friend Matrix<T>        operator* <>(const T& t, const Matrix& mtrx);
    Matrix                  operator*(const T&) const;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KjzhrMheK)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Not something I would have thought of, the parameter lists should clearly declare them as separate overloads. Thanks for the comprehensive answer, and yes, it compiles fine for me now. I will have to remember to keep the friends first then.

I almost didn't include that other version of operator* in my post though, would you have been able to diagnose the problem if I hadn't, I wonder?

Comment: @HanLi I assume you're talking about not including the nontemplate version of `operator*`. If that were the case then there would've been no error because then the lookup would not have found the nontemplate `operator*`(since there wouldn't be any). See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7bsqxGGd) where i've commented out the nontemplate `operator*` as you were thinking of doing i assume. You're welcome :)

Comment: Yes, except I meant removing it from the post only. It is still part of my actual class, the post does not represent the entire class. Only the parts I thought were relevant to the question. Except I didn't expect it to be relevant to include both versions of operator*. I just happened to include it anyway, more to illustrate I didn't actually need to make a friend here. And it turned out to be the cause of my problem after all.

Comment: @HanLi Just to confirm that we are on the same page you mean that you were thinking of removing the nontemplate member function `operator*` or the friend declaration of specialization of template version? If you were thinking of removing the nontemplate member function `operator*` completely then yes we would not get any error for the reason explained above. I mean in this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7bsqxGGd) i've completely removed the nontemplate version `operator*` and so we don't get any error here.

Comment: Yest, the nontemplate member function. But only from the post describing my problem, not from my code. I still need those, I have a total of three overloaded operator* in my code. Multilying matrix by matrix, multiplying matrix by scalar and multiplying scalar by matrix. The last of which has to be then non-member version. I almost only included the non-member template version in my post.

Comment: @HanLi I see. And if you were to not include the nontemplate version in this post then  it would've been not possible to diagnose the error.