# Why does MSVC not complain about the expression i.str() where i is an int?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I got some ill-formed code like the following, but it builds with MSVC 19.32.31329 and /std:c++latest.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

template<typename T>
void foo() {
    int i;
    // Can be anything that looks like a function call
    baz(i.str());
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    int i;
    // The following line is wrong because i has an integral type
    // and doesn't have .str().
    i.str();
}
```

The code is clearly wrong and shouldn't compile, but [it does](https://godbolt.org/z/zeb1onKhE). Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: `ms.str()` -> `ss.str()`

Comment: Of course I know ms should be changed to ss but why does this code build?

Comment: [I can't replicate that](https://godbolt.org/z/jMPEYfMaG). Is the code you show really a copy-paste of the actual code you build? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: if msvc encounters multiple errors of the same kind (close together) it often displays only the last one. If you correct only the last one (and missed the previous one) it will display that one in the next compile.

Comment: Hi, this is the minimal reproducible code https://godbolt.org/z/e4Kqv8noT

Comment: That's not minimal (why is `foo` there when no-one actually instantiates it?). Also, please read the link again. The [mcve] **must** be part of the question.

Comment: That `foo` function template is all it takes for the code to build, which is really weird. If I add the function to my own example it will build, and if I take it away from your code it results in the expected errors.

Comment: It also seems that the call to `OutputDebugString` doesn't happen in the main function, which is weird. I'd argue there's a bug in the MSVC compiler.

Comment: Here's the [actual mcve](https://godbolt.org/z/s51WdWxn8) (and an [updated version](https://godbolt.org/z/8oPTrnaG5) as well).

Comment: I've added a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sWozvf59r) in the where the program compiles without any problem/error.

Comment: @JackBranson **[This](https://godbolt.org/z/sWozvf59r) is not a bug**. I've explained the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72376365/12002570) in the dupe. If you actually call the function like `foo<int>();` you will get error saying: *" invalid literal suffix 'str'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""str' not found"*

Comment: `42.str` is a valid user-defined floating point literal, with suffix `str`. The lookup for `operator "" str` is delayed until the template is actually instantiated.

Comment: @jas You failed to understand here. The issue isn't with the function template. The issue is that the function template apparently teaches the compiler new language rules. The **real** issue is `i.str()` in `WinMain`.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, `i.str()` should still not compile which it doesn't. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eK9h1njWa). If you add the function template with a call like `baz(i.str());` then `i.str()` compiles. Seem like a **msvc bug**.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik custom user-defined literal must begin with `_` so I don't think `42.str` is valid

Comment: @jas There's *literally* a [link](https://godbolt.org/z/zeb1onKhE) in the question that demonstrates that it **does** compile.

Comment: @phuclv "Must" here is really "should" - the compiler doesn't enforce it. It's a library requirement: "**[usrlit.suffix]/1** Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization." It is true that the program that uses such suffix exhibits undefined behavior; but it's not ill-formed. Maybe I should have said "well-formed user-defined literal", rather than "valid".

Comment: I've submitted a bug report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem)

Comment: Please don't edit the code above, someone has caused misleading.

Comment: Please don't edit your question once an answer has been submitted. I'll roll back those changes (since they make the issue less clear, and partially invalidate answers).

Comment: The code above is NOT the original question, and it doesn't show the difference between OutputDebugString and other functions.
My question was:
`OutputDebugString(<int value>.str())` builds but `std::string{<int value>.str()}`  doesn't

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `OutputDebugString`. I don't see a reason why it should be there. Neither are strings, stringstreams, or chrono types related. The code edited in by me captures the core issue.

Comment: Please could you have a look at this example? (https://godbolt.org/z/5eeKrnGTP) The code does not compile (which is an expected behaviour) because I changed `OutputDebugString` to `std::string{ms.str().c_str()};`.

Comment: The function call in the function template is the crucial piece. You can reproduce the correct behavior (i.e. the code doesn't compile) when simply using `ms.str();` in place of the `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a [compiler bug](https://godbolt.org/z/nG3z9Kasf) that was apparently [introduced](https://godbolt.org/z/q3s8TrhGW) in version 19.32. It can be observed when compiling either with `/std:c++latest` or `/std:c++20`.

It appears that anything that's inside a function template can trick MSVC into learning new rules about integral types. As illustrated in the question once the compiler is through parsing `foo` it will subsequently allow any expression `exp` of integral type to have any (fantasy) member (such as `str()`) invoked (verified with integers, floating point values, booleans, pointers and arrays).

---

A related issue was [brought up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434575/why-does-msvc-not-complain-about-the-expression-i-str-where-i-is-an-int#comment129686145_73434575) in a comment on the question.

While the function template `foo` *is* instantiated here, MSVC [will compile](https://godbolt.org/z/EKxrebqoe) the following code:

```cpp
extern void bar(int);

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    int i;
    // This should not compile
    bar(i.str());
}

int WinMain(void*, void*, char*, int)
{
    foo<int>();
}
```

Although this could be following rule [[temp.res.general/6.4]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.4) to the letter of the law:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - ...
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

Indeed, changing `int i` to `auto i = sizeof(T)` [fails](https://godbolt.org/z/d7K7vPxja) to compile. This might be unrelated.

---

A bug report has been issued (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73435650/1889329)).

Answer (score 2):

This is a msvc bug. The program is **ill-formed no diagnostic required**. This can be seen from [temp#res.general6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1) which states:

> 6. The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>
> **The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if**:
>
> - 6.1)  **no valid specialization can be generated for a template** or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template **and the template is not instantiated**, or

Additionally, [temp#res.general6.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.4) also applies here:

> a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

(emphasis mine)

---

A bug report for the same has been submitted as:

[The call `someint.str()` compiles when invalid function template is present](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-call-someintstr-compiles-when-inv/10126411)

Comment: The program is actually IFNDR because of https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1 and IFNDR takes precedence over other violations that would make the program ill-formed, but still that seems like a quality-of-implementation issue that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @use If I understand, a conforming compiler can - once it hits a violation that falls into the IFNDR category - choose to remain silent about all other violations even when they would otherwise require a diagnostic? In that case this wouldn't *actually* be a compiler bug then, rather than a quality-of-implementation regression. Right?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, that is what I am saying. But if a compiler did this intentionally, I would consider it malicious. MSVC must be somehow deciding what code to generate for the `.str()` call in main with no sensible choice. So it does seem unintentional that it doesn't fail with an error there. I think this allowance by the standard is just a side-effect of how it is written. The intention of the rule I linked is that the compiler can help detect mistakes early, not to silently miscompile.

Comment: @use Ok, thanks. Though the compiler also [remains silent](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yr86esoo) in case the template is actually instantiated. So probably a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable Even with instantiation https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.4 would still apply.

Comment: @IInspectable FYI: I posted a question asking to clarify whether I am correct on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436932/does-ifndr-take-precedence-over-diagnosable-rule-violations. From all I have heard IFNDR should technically take precendence, but I never found that part of the standard specified clearly.