# Does IFNDR take precedence over diagnosable rule violations?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[intro.compliance.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.compliance.general#2) specifies how a compiler should handle a program given to it.

In particular it has two points dealing with ill-formed programs. (2.2) requires the compiler to issue at least one diagnostic for a violation of a diagnosable rule. (2.3) states that there are no requirements imposed on the compiler for a program which violates a rule for which no diagnostic is required.

Unfortunately I don't think the paragraph makes a precedence between the two requirements clear. If a program contains a violation of a diagnosable rule for which a diagnostic is required and a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, is the compiler required to issue a diagnostic?

As an example (considered as a whole one-translation-unit program):

```
// ill-formed, diagnostic required
int main() { using T = void&; }

// IFNDR according to [temp.res.general]/8.1 and [temp.res.general]/8.4
void f(auto) { using T = void&; }
```

Moreover, if IFNDR takes precedence, the same presumably applies to undefined behavior that is typically considered runtime UB, e.g. does

```
// always runtime undefined behavior
int main() { return *(int*)0; }

// ill-formed, diagnostic required
using T = void&;
```

then technically also not require a diagnostic (considered as a whole one-translation-unit program)?

---

From a quality-of-implementation standpoint it seems clear to me that the compiler should issue a diagnostic whenever possible in such a situation.

But my impression is that the standard does not actually require one and this is also what I have read/heard before. For example the qualification of "*and the template is not instantiated*" in [[temp.res.general]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.1) would not make much sense otherwise. However at other times the standard doesn't use such inverting qualifications where it seems that they should be required, e.g. [[dcl.constexpr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#6).

Comment: It's not a question of precedence. The two situations are distinct. The question of precedence between them therefore does not arise. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 Simplified question: Does the standard require a conforming compiler to issue a diagnostic for either of the two programs I am showing? And as far as I can tell that is a question of whether the referenced (2.3) supersedes the requirement of (2.2) if it applies.

Comment: 2.2 and 2.3 cannot both apply to the same piece of code. The compiler is required by 2.2 to issue a diagnostic for the second piece and by 2.3 not for the first piece. These two facts have nothing to do with each other. There is no 'superceding' or 'precedence' involved.

Comment: @user207421 The first program I am showing in my question satisfies both the condition "_If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule_" from (2.2) and "_If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required_" from (2.3). So both apply. The question is whether the effect of (2.3) negates the requirement for a diagnostic in (2.2). Also, are you considering _undefined behavior_ for all inputs to be different from _ill-formed, no diagnostic required_ here? I thought that these would generally be considered equivalent.

Comment: @user17732522 _2.2 and 2.3 cannot both apply to the same piece of code_ 2.2 and 2.3 apply not to pisses of code, but to an implementation processing the program.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I think you tagged the wrong user. Also, typo?

Comment: _I think you tagged the wrong user_ Indeed. _Also, typo?_ Maybe. Maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 2.3 is clear – *"this document places no requirement on implementations".* Not "this document except for 2.2", but "this document". **If an IFNDR situation exists, then the implementation is free to do anything.**

### Necessary

Overriding 2.2 is necessary. Hypothetically, an IFNDR situation could throw compilation off-track, resulting in it missing an ill-formed situation that does require a diagnostic. (Bugs hidden by other bugs is not a novel concept.) This does not make the implementation non-conforming. The existence of the IFNDR situation gives implementations the leeway they need to potentially miss a diagnostic in related code despite good-faith processing.

This does mean that implementations also have leeway to miss a diagnostic in unrelated code. Oh well. The standard could try to distinguish between "related code" and "unrelated code", but it would be wasted effort. At some point, it is better to trust that implementations work in good faith, rather than excessively regulate.

A "diagnostic not required" scenario is a valid *reason* for missing a diagnostic. If an implementation uses it as an *excuse* to actively omit a diagnostic, then it is compliant, but you should stay away.
Just like you should stay far away from a compliant implementation that detects undefined behavior and uses that as an excuse to format your hard drive.

### Practical

From a **practical** perspective, though, 2.3 does not override 2.2. While the official terminology is "no diagnostic required", a more practical view is "the situation does not need to be detected". Situations that require a diagnostic must be detected so that the diagnostic can be produced. Situations that do not require any particular action by the implementation do not need to be detected.

If an implementation does not try to detect an IFNDR situation, then it cannot make decisions based upon the IFNDR existing. That is, it must provide diagnostics for the ill-formedness that it does detect. This is not just "quality-of-implementation", nor is it just "good faith", but rather it is necessary to ensure compliance in the face of an unknown.

If an implementation *does* detect an IFNDR situation, then we fall back on good faith.

Comment: Regarding your second-to-last paragraph: I could at least in theory imagine a compiler using absence of IFNDR as an axiom for compile-time optimization. For example if a `constexpr` function would unconditionally evaluate some subexpression which doesn't depend on the arguments, then it could be assumed to be a constant subexpression and as long as the full constant expression doesn't depend on its result, could simply be ignored without verifying that it is indeed a constant subexpression, potentially affecting semantics of the program and missing otherwise diagnosable violations.

Comment: But that probably has negligible benefits and I think that would be against the intent of these IFNDR rules though.

Comment: @user17732522 *"I could at least in theory imagine a compiler using absence of IFNDR as an axiom for compile-time optimization."* -- that is valid. Either IFNDR occurs, in which case no requirement is placed on the compiler so a false axiom is acceptable, or IFNDR does not occur and the axiom holds. However, thinking in terms of the benefits that could come from such an axiom is probably not the way to go. I think more effective would be to focus on the potential optimizations; when evaluating the cost/benefit of a particular optimizations, you may ignore complications that imply IFNDR.

Answer (score -1):

The wording is precise. The wording in question says:

> ... this document places no requirement ...

This would obviously include a requirement that this clause supercedes all other clauses, and specifically 2.2

Clause 2.2 still applies. It is still effective. The applicability of 2.3 has no effect on 2.2 by the plain wording of 2.3.

Since the program is still diagnosable as ill-formed with respect to 2.2, then a diagnostic, with respect to what 2.2 applies to, is still required.

It goes without saying that this is the intuitive interpretation. It would make no practical sense for some non-diagnosable condition in some function will make the compiler not complain about some completely different function attempting to return an `int`, when it should return a `void`.

Comment: I am honestly not sure which direction you are arguing. As you say "_this document places no requirement_" points to it superseding everything else, meaning that there would be no requirement to diagnose any other violation if a IFNDR violation is present. But the rest of your answer seems to argue that diagnosable violations must still be diagnosed? Or are you just saying that it would be an unreasonable implementation if it did not behave that way?

Comment: "this document places no requirement" is with respect to the NDR violation. The scope of that statement is limited strictly to the NDR violation. Nothing about every other requirement, other than NDR violations, changes.

Comment: So then do the example programs in my question require a diagnostic to be issued in your interpretation?

Comment: If a program is ill-formed, and a diagnostic is required, then a diagnostic is required. The presence of any other ill-formability that does not require a diagnostic does not void the requirement to issue a diagnostic when it's required.