# Overload resolution of templated functions taking no parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

While doing some tests with overload resolution regarding templated functions, I noticed some discrepancies between the results of some of the mainstream C++ compilers (Clang 15, GCC 12.2, MSVC 19.33). I'm not too familiar with the intricacies of [function template overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) but I would like to know which of the following function overloads is legal C++ code (while adhering to the C++20 standard) and which overload resolution should lead to ambiguities.

Which of the presented function overloads (each test case separated by their own namespace) should be legal C++20 code? And which function overload should be ambiguous?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/1K3aW3e7s):

```
//////////////// ellipsis ////////////////

// #e1 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace e1 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(...);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #e2 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace e2 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(...);

    template<typename..., typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #e3 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: illegal & ambiguous (trunk: illegal)
namespace e3 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(...);

    template<typename... Ts, typename...>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #e4 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: illegal & ambiguous (trunk: illegal)
namespace e4 {
    template<typename..., typename...>
    void f(...);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #e5 | clang: ambiguous | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace e5 {
    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts..., ...);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #e6 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ambiguous
namespace e6 {
    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts..., ...);

    template<typename...>
    void f(...);
}

//////////////// defaulted argument ////////////////

// #d1 | clang: ok (trunk: ambiguous) | gcc: ok | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace d1 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #d2 | clang: ok (trunk: ambiguous) | gcc: ok | msvc: illegal & amb. (trunk: ill.)
namespace d2 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename... Ts, typename...>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #d3 | clang: ok (trunk: ambiguous) | gcc: ok | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace d3 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename..., typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts...);
}

// #d4 | clang: ambiguous (trunk: ok) | gcc: ok | msvc: ok
namespace d4 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
    void f(Ts..., Us...);
}

// #d5 | clang: ambiguous | gcc: ok | msvc: illegal
namespace d5 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename... Ts, typename...>
    void f(Ts..., ...);
}

// #d6 | clang: ok (trunk: ambiguous) | gcc: ok | msvc: illegal & ambiguous
namespace d6 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename..., typename... Ts>
    void f(Ts..., ...);
}

// #d7 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ok
namespace d7 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(bool = true, Ts...);
}

// #d8 | clang: ok | gcc: ambiguous | msvc: ambiguous (trunk: ok)
namespace d8 {
    template<typename...>
    void f(bool = true, ...);

    template<typename... Ts>
    void f(bool = true, Ts...);
}
```

Overview test results:

```
 Test | Clang 15  | Clang trunk | GCC 12.2  | GCC trunk | MSVC 19.33     | MSVC trunk
------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------
  #e1 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | ambiguous      | ok
  #e2 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | ambiguous      | ok
  #e3 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | illegal & amb. | illegal
  #e4 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | illegal & amb. | illegal
  #e5 | ambiguous | ambiguous   | ambiguous | ambiguous | ambiguous      | ok
  #e6 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | ambiguous      | ok
      |           |             |           |           |                |
  #d1 | ok        | ambiguous   | ok        | ok        | ambiguous      | ok
  #d2 | ok        | ambiguous   | ok        | ok        | illegal & amb. | illegal
  #d3 | ok        | ambiguous   | ok        | ok        | ambiguous      | ok
  #d4 | ambiguous | ok          | ok        | ok        | ok             | ok
  #d5 | ambiguous | ambiguous   | ok        | ok        | illegal        | illegal
  #d6 | ok        | ambiguous   | ok        | ok        | illegal & amb. | ill. & amb.
  #d7 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | ok             | ok
  #d8 | ok        | ok          | ambiguous | ambiguous | ambiguous      | ok
```

---

As requested, here are some samples of the error messages produced. The error produced by Clang 15 with test case `d4`:

```
<source>:135:28: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
static_assert(not noexcept(f()));
                           ^
<source>:89:10: note: candidate function [with $0 = <>]
    void f(bool = true);
         ^
<source>:92:10: note: candidate function [with Ts = <>, Us = <>]
    void f(Ts..., Us...);
         ^
```

The error produced by GCC 12.2 with test case `d7`:

```
<source>:135:29: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
  135 | static_assert(not noexcept(f()));
      |                            ~^~
<source>:116:10: note: candidate: 'void d7::f(bool)
                 [with <template-parameter-1-1> = {}]'
  116 |     void f(bool = true);
      |          ^
<source>:119:10: note: candidate: 'void d7::f(bool, Ts ...) [with Ts = {}]'
  119 |     void f(bool = true, Ts...);
      |          ^
```

The error produced by MSVC 19.33 with test case `e3`:

```
<source>(27): error C3547: template parameter '<unnamed-symbol>' cannot be used
              because it follows a template parameter pack and cannot be deduced
              from the function parameters of 'e3::f'
<source>(27): note: see declaration of '<unnamed-symbol>'
<source>(135): error C2668: 'e3::f': ambiguous call to overloaded function
<source>(27): note: could be 'void e3::f<,>(void)'
<source>(24): note: or       'void e3::f<>(...)'
<source>(135): note: while trying to match the argument list '()'
<source>(135): error C2056: illegal expression
<source>(135): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Comment: Please update your question with a sampling of the messages that indicate ambiguous and error along with the code that generates those messages

Comment: @ChrisSc The error messages are simply `call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous`. Just check the live example linked in the question.

Comment: @303 the reason for (some) errors in the question is: someone may be searching for similar errors and comments can be temporary and removed by the system.

Comment: @RichardCritten Alright, I've added some of the error messages produced by the compilers. I hope that will help with searching.

Comment: I don't think that the code is illegal C++20 as much as having multiple declarations of the same function with the same parameter options causes ambiguity: such as `d2` having two declarations that can handle no parameters as (shown in the errors in your question). How compilers resolve ambiguity is up to the compiler implementer. It's better to avoid ambiguity, such as removing the default value on the bool parameter for example. Compilers may choose the wrong way to resolve an ambiguity for your purposes

Comment: This is low key hilarious and I could not upvote it more.

Comment: @ChrisSc *"How compilers resolve ambiguity is up to the compiler implementer."* This is what the C++ standard is for, so that the compiler implementors don't have to guess how to implement a certain feature. C++ programmers take a lot effort to make sure their programs are compliant with the rules of C++, so that they can expect their programs to behave the same way, regardless of the platform it is run on or what compiler they use. Adhering to the C++ standard starts to become rather pointless when all of the well-known compilers don't agree on anything.

Comment: I agree with you on standards removing ambiguity. However, I think it's a little strong to say that well-known compilers don't agree on anything. Good luck on your search, I'm looking forward to hearing about your resolution

Comment: I think this should be broken up into one question per test case.

Comment: @BrianBi Well, the thing is... there are even more test cases, probably too much to list (one function having no defaulted argument nor ellipsis, or using some a combination of 3 or more variadic template arguments). Since there seems to be some variance between the latest stable releases and trunk builds of some of the compilers, it might indicate that some defect report or proposal has been (or will likely be) accepted. And that might be applicable/shed some light on the underlying issue of most of these discrepancies.

Comment: I don't think anything you said is an argument against breaking up the question. At present the question is too large and even if there is an applicable defect report, it would take a massive amount of time to explain the rules applicable to all the test cases at once.

Comment: When the all is OK for one compiler, it might be useful to know which one is selected... Probably a bunch of example would fall in the category **This program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**. Most of them are absolute non sense.

Comment: The program is **ill-formed no diagnostic required**. See [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375794/template-class-compiles-with-c17-but-not-with-c20-if-unused-function-cant-b) and [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434575/why-does-msvc-not-complain-about-the-expression-i-str-where-i-is-an-int).

Comment: @Jason Those two questions are wildly unrelated to this one. Also this is definitely not IFNDR: every case is either one or the other is the best match or is ambiguous.

Comment: @303 One question per post.

Comment: IMO this is one question with several facets