# Why the template parameter should be used here for function call of decltype when define a template function with a trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-templates

when using a trailing return type in C++ template function, the function call
in decltype with template parameter as follows will compile successfully.

```cpp
// case 1: no error
template <typename T>
struct basic_type { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
auto getBox1() -> decltype((getBox(basic_type<T>{})))
{
    return getBox(basic_type<T>{});
}
```

if the parameter of function `getBox` is void, a gramma error would assert immediately.

```cpp
// case 2: error
template <typename T>
struct basic_type { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
auto getBox1() -> decltype((getBox())) // ERROR TIPS, "identifier "getBox" is undefined"
{
    return getBox();
}
```

since `getBox` function is not declared or defined either case, why case 1 is OK but case 2 would give an error?

Any explanation would be great appreciated.

googled this problem, but the seach engine could even not parse the content.

Comment: So seems IFNDR. Here is perhaps a more straightforward [example](https://godbolt.org/z/1b5WrasP4).

Comment: What does this have to do with trailing-return-type? I can repro even without it. The first case is theoretically valid because `getBox` can be found via ADL. The second case it outright invalid if there's no `getBox` visible at template definition.

Comment: I've opened this. The dupe target just explains what is IFNDR, but not the difference between the two cases.

Comment: At OP see also [Template class compiles with C++17 but not with C++20 if unused function can't be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375794/template-class-compiles-with-c17-but-not-with-c20-if-unused-function-cant-b?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Jason As I said, the first one is legal because of ADL: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7jb5dWPs3

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see. So only the second one is IFNDR.

Comment: TLDR: If you get the template argument involved, the check gets delayed until the argument is known, otherwise it's done immediately.

Comment: Would it be clearer for OP to precise what ADL implies here? First case, ```getBox``` explicitely depend on the template parameter, thus the compiler must wait for a specialization to see if ```getBox``` exists, which might be the case at instanciation point. Second case, ```getBox``` is not dependant, the compiler knows that, whatever ```T``` ```getBox``` is required and it can check right now: indeed it does not find a declaration, it fails.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili Sorry I didn't see your comment which sums up clearly my lengthy one.